# Закрыть доступ к файлам папки

Tags: .htaccess, php

Привет! У меня на сайте реализована модульная система, все модули хранятся в папке mod, соответственно нужно закрыть доступ ко всем файлам данной папки, т.е файлы должны инклюдиться, но не должны запрашиваться извне. Индексация папок запрещена, но запретить файл все равно можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если у тебя единственная точка входа index.php, то в начале каждого файла пропиши подобную строчку

```
 defined("SYSTEM") or die('Permission denied');
```

если попытаться достучаться к файлу напрямую, то выведет Permission denied. Только где-то в index.php не забудь установить константу SYSTEM

Comment: @mountpoint Точно! Я и забыл про этот метод, спасибо!